# can't find file explorer in android studio

Tags: android-studio, explorer

I'm using Android Studio 1.2.1.1
I'm looking for the File Explorer from the Android Device Monitor...
I see nothing:

[image]

Comment: tools->Android->device monitor

Comment: I have the same problem. Opening the device monitor does not show a file explorer tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in the end, the problem was that the file explorer was being opened in a separated tab BEHIND the IDE.